# Using the glob() function with an array and wildcard search

Tags: php

I currently have an array which holds file names, I now want to `foreach` through this array using a wildcard search in a directory and find the matching files.

How can I do this using the `glob()` function?

Comment: Please share some of your code and what you've tried so far

Comment: where is your tried script?

Comment: <?php
foreach (glob($c.'*.txt') as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . "\n";
}
?>

Comment: I have to use the $filename output under indexed string variable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this to extract each file which matches your **wildcard** search inside a foreach loop:

```
$search = "*.txt";
// if this is what you mean by indexed string variable?
$file = array("updated.txt", "new.txt"); 

// getcwd() will retrieve the current directory but is not needed - this just shows
// that you can supply a directory if you wanted to.

function MatchFile($file,$search)
{
    $temp = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach (glob(getcwd().$search) as $filename) :
        if (count($file) > $i):
            array_push($temp, ($filename == $file[$i++])? $filename : "");
        else:
            // stops the index overflow error
            break;
        endif;
    endforeach;
    return $temp;
}

foreach (MatchFile($file,$search) as $found):
    echo $found . " was found!";
endforeach;
```

This is just a replacement of `opendir();`.

If you're still unsure or need to know more flags, you can use this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for help.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the $filename output under indexed string variable. Can I?

Comment: You lost me at `indexed string variable`, however, you can access variables outside of the foreach scope if that is what you're asking. For example, see updated answer.

Comment: Not a problem, good luck with your Project - just remember to add your checks and comment your code :)

Comment: array_push ... what a great idea!

Comment: Yes, however, this could be better solved using a more OOP approach - maybe try this for better practice?